# Read a txt file from my server using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text

I know this kind of questions have been asked a numerous times. But i am confused as no answer really helped me.

**Problem:**

I have a .txt file on `http://example.come/test.txt`.

And I want to do is display all the contents of the txt file using JS in a test.html file.

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: If you're using jQuery, have you tried any of these: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/, http://api.jquery.com/load/ specifically?

Comment: http://www.scriptsplash.com/2009/07/simple-ajax-request-loading-text-file.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an Ajax call to receive the contents of the text file and than insert it into you DOM. It should be something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $.get('text.txt', function(data) {
                $('#text-file-container').html(data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="text-file-container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: hi there,i tried the above as an example. and nothing happens. it shows nothing.

Comment: I am getting this error ```Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin. ```

Comment: @softwareisfun I guess it need a to be run on an actual server. Ajax calls are restricted to be run on the client-side.